# How to use upstream triggers in declarative Jenkisfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**What is the correct usage of the upstream trigger in a declarative Jenkinsfile?**

I'm trying to add dependency triggers, so that the pipeline is triggered after another project has built successfully.

The jenkisci doku on github is listing upstream events as possible pipeline triggers [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Trigger-runs).

My Jenkisfile is currently looking like this:

```
pipeline {
agent { 
    docker {
        ...
    }
}
options {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'10'))
}

triggers {
    upstream 'project-name,other-project-name', hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
}
```

which leads to the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 16: Arguments to "upstream" must be explicitly named. @ line 16, column 9.
       upstream 'project-name,other-project-name', hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
       ^
```

**Update**

I changed the syntax for the upstream trigger according to the code snippet [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers). So, now there is at least no syntax error anymore. But the trigger is still not working as intended.

```
 triggers {
    upstream(
        upstreamProjects: 'project-name,other-project-name', 
        threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
}
```

If I understand the documentation correctly this pipeline should be triggered if one of the two declared jobs has completed successfully right?

Comment: In pipeline configuration you should find section *Build Triggers* and under that option *Build after other projects are built*

Comment: @minas thanks! But is there any way to do that via infrastructure as code?

Answer (score 3):

If both projects are in same folder and jenkins is aware of jenkinsfile (with below mentioned code) of downstream project(i.e downstream project has ran atleast once), this should work for you :

```
   triggers {  
        upstream(upstreamProjects: "../projectA/master", threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still relatively new to Jenkins and I have been struggling to get this to work, too. Specifically, I thought that just saving the pipeline code with the *triggers* directive in the web UI editor would connect the two jobs. It **doesn't**.

However, if one then *manually runs* the downstream job, the `upstream...` code in its pipeline appears to *modify* the job definition and configure the triggers, resulting in the same situation one would have if they had just set things up in the "build triggers" section of the job config form. In other words, the directive appears to be just a way to tell Jenkins to do the web UI config work for you, when/if the job gets run for some reason.

I spent hours on this and it could have been documented better. Also, the "declarative directive generator" in Jenkins for triggers gave me something like `upstream threshold: 'FAILURE'` which resulted in something like:

`WorkflowScript: 5: Expecting "class hudson.model.Result" for parameter "threshold" but got "FAILURE" of type class java.lang.String instead @ line 5, column 23.`

To fix this I had to change the parameter to read `upstream threshold: hudson.model.Result.FAILURE`. Fair enough, but then the generator is broken. Not impressed.